# Why does the Cat class use Cat parent as instance variable?

Tags: java, swing, class

I am a beginner in Java programming. I don't understand what this code does. In the cat class, I don't understand the variable Cat parent. Which value will it hold?

```
public class Solution {

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

    String motherName = reader.readLine();
    Cat catMother = new Cat(motherName);

    String daughterName = reader.readLine();
    Cat catDaughter = new Cat(daughterName, catMother);

    System.out.println(catMother);
    System.out.println(catDaughter);
}

public static class Cat {
    private String name;
    private Cat parent;

    Cat(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    Cat(String name, Cat parent) {
        this.name = name;
        this.parent = parent;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        if (parent == null)
            return "The cat's name is " + name + ", no mother ";
        else
            return "The cat's name is " + name + ", " + parent.name + " is the mother";
    }
}
```

It is confusing when I see Cat parent declared as a variable in the Cat Class!

Comment: The parent is also a Cat.

Comment: A `Cat` has a parent, and this parent is a `Cat` too. In your code the `parent` field will contain a reference to the current `Cat`s parent (or `null` if no parent has been provided)

Comment: You can have class variables of its own type. A cat's parent, logically, would also be a cat. Nothing in Java will prevent you from doing this and it is in fact very useful once you learn more complex data structures.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at the lines in your `main` method...

This line creates a new `Cat` with a name (that was defined by input before):

```
Cat catMother = new Cat(motherName);
```

while the following line also creates a new `Cat`, but uses a different constructor (the one with two arguments):

```
Cat catDaughter = new Cat(daughterName, catMother);
```

If you just read the names of the arguments, you can clearly see a relationship... Using this constructor gives the new `Cat` a name (daughter) and a relative (mother). This relative is stored as an attribute in the `Cat` class. So every instance of `Cat` has another `Cat` as a parent or `null` (the latter could lead to some different problems).

Then have a look at the class attributes of the `Cat`, this is where the values are set (or not):

```
private String name; // this is where the name of the cat object is stored
private Cat parent;  // this is where mother or father is stored (yes, only one possible at a time)
```

It is pretty common in Java to have an instance of some class having another instance of the same class as an attribute, which is nothing different to an object of the class `String`, just another type of object.

Answer (score 1):

Cat parent is Cat object assigned to another Cat object.

Here Cat parent is created:

```
String motherName = reader.readLine();
Cat catMother = new Cat(motherName);
```

And here it is assigned to another Cat object "catDaughter"

```
String daughterName = reader.readLine();
Cat catDaughter = new Cat(daughterName, catMother);
```

In other word with parent field you can create a relationship between a few Cat objects.

Comment: OK i get it, when motherName is input, it is passed to the variable name, and when daughterName is input, it is still passed to name but now motherName is passed to parent name, that is what i understand??

Comment: The different between Cat Parent and Cat Child objects is in the used constructor. If you use Cat(String name) - this cat has no child, if you type Cat(String name, Cat parent)  - then you assigning parent to the current object